# "One's" in a sentence

Tags: meaning

In this sentence I can not understand if "one's" refers to proving your identity or proving the identity of someone else.

> The ability to prove one's identity is a universal human right

Comment: in this case, it refers to proving one's own identity. Otherwise, it would say "someone's"

Comment: "one" has almost the same meaning here as "someone"  but fits in a different grammatical slot. It does not mean "I".  It means that each person has a right to prove that person's own identity. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"One" is (in such a use) a general pronoun, standing for an unspecified or generic person.

> The ability to prove one's identity is a universal human right

means that any and every person has this right.

Consider such sentences as:

> - When one is lost, it may help to ask a police officer.
> - There is never enough money to do all the things that one might want to do.
> - One should try to avoid offending others.
> - One tries to avoid offending others.
> - One feels sorry for the victim, but what can one do.

The word "one" (used in this way, not as a number) can usually be replaced by "a person".  Often it can also be replaced by "I" or "You", but with a subtle change in meaning.

Using "one" is often a way of generalizing a statement; of making it less personal than if "I" had been used. It is also often a way of avoiding a gender-specific pronouns such as "he".

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to say : The ability one to prove one's identity is a universal human right ?

Comment: @Kosg
 No, that would not be correct at all. "One's" in the given sentence modifies "identity" indicating whose identity is to be proved. Try substituting "his" for "one's":  "The ability his to prove his identity..." just does not work, while "The ability to prove his identity..." works quite well, One could write something like "one's ability to prove ones own identity..." but it doesn't add much to the meaning, just a matter of style.

Comment: So, one has the right to prove one's identity is the meaning

Comment: @Kosg Yes, that is correct

Comment: Thank you david !

Comment: @Kosg when you think an answer is **the** correct answer you can "accept" it by checking the ckeckmark (aka tickmark) to the ledt to the answer. When you have a little more reputation, you can also upvote any answers you think are useful to yourself or othes. You can only accept one aswer (at  time) per question, but you can upvote as many as you see fit. Only the asker can accept answers, but any user (with a bit of rep) can upvote or downvote answers. Accepting and upvoting are perhaps the best way to thank an answerer.